# How can I prevent LibreOffice Calc from removing the plus (+) sign?

Tags: libreoffice

The following GIF animation demonstrates the problem.

[image: GIF animation]

Comment: format the cell as text

Comment: FWIW, I'd consider this a SuperUser question rather than Ubuntu one. It's completely unrelated to Ubuntu, and works exactly the same on other (e.g. Windows) LibreOffice versions.

Comment: @vaxquis LibreOffice is installed by default on Ubuntu. Therefore, it is on topic on SU but also here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply add a apostrophe when entering your data - turns the cell into a text cell :)

```
'+888888
```

If you need to use the number and cannot have it as text, you need to create a number format for it.

Right click and select **Format Cells... -> Numbers**. Enter your format into the **Format Code** field. The easiest format would be `+0`, which will display your number with a + and keep it a number, so it can be used in formulas.

[image: format cells dialogue]

Comment: This is identical to the behaviour in (and probably brought over from) Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Naaa - even Lotus 1-2-3 and Lotus Symphony had it in old times. I would bet Visicalc as the mother of spreadsheets had it. In fact, there is not much in Excel that was not "brought over" from another program.

Comment: Although if you only use `+0` as the _format code_ and you enter a negative number, eg. `-123` you'll get `-+123` as the formatted result, which is probably not the desired outcome. Use `+0;-0` to handle negative numbers (as mentioned in [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1153151/80205)).

Answer (score 23):

## Use `+0;-0;0` as a number format

This answer **automates** the desired formatting for both positive and negative numbers.

Semicolons are required as separators between positive, negative and zero number formats.

The [official LibreOffice documentation on Number Format Codes](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/01/05020301.html?&DbPAR=SHARED) could benefit from a better example like this case.

[image: Format Cells Number]

Comment: IMHO, it's a much better answer than the other one, since it provides automatic formatting for both positive and negative numbers and allows to keep the numeric format. Thanks!

Comment: I used `+0;-0;±0` as number format to display differences.